# Estoy con programa en pascal y no me sale

Tags: pascal, freepascal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][[image: Es el problema a resolver, tengo que poner un numero mayor a 100 y que me diga todos los numeros que cumplan la propiedad en donde se repitan 2 digitos.]

Es el problema a resolver, tengo que poner un numero mayor a 100 y que me diga todos los numeros que cumplan la propiedad en donde se repitan 2 digitos. Hasta ahora hice lo que ven, pero nose que hacer. nose como combianr las funciones y los procedimientos.

Comment: Pon el codigo que has intentado y cuentanos que errores te da para poderte ayudar. Entendemos el ejercicio, pero aqui no realizamos tareas completas, ayudamos a realizar tareas que ya estan iniciadas y no sepais continuar, donde se demuestre un esfuerzo por parte del que pregunta.

Comment: ahi agregue lo que tengo hasta ahora pero no es mucho, estoy muy trabado en este ejercicio

Comment: estuve toda la tarde con esto encima

Comment: El código de la pregunta debe ir como texto, no como imagen, pues para facilitar que podamos responderte e interesarnos por tu pregunta, necesitamos copiar y pegar tu código en nuestros dispositivos para intentar encontrar una solución.  Si es una imagen nos obligas a escribirlo todo y no se si nadie tendrá tantas ganas de hacerlo, normalmente no, y es probable que eso impida que tengas respuestas y/o buenas respuestas.

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.